# Typescript key value pair to conditional object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Assume I have a type

```
type MyType = {
   'KEY1': 'ValueForKey1';
   'KEY2': 'ValueForKey2';
   'KEY3': 'ValueForKey3';
}
```

and I have function which takes values from MyType as `{key: 'KEY1', value: 'ValueForKey1'}`

```
function myFunc(entry: MyParamType<MyType>) {

}
```

Where I defined `MyParamType` as

```
type MyParamType<T> = {
    key: keyof T;
    value: T[keyof T]
};
```

This works fine for

```
myFunc({
    key: 'KEY1',
    value: 'ValueForKey1'
})
```

and fails as expected for

```
myFunc({
    key: 'KEY1',
    value: 'ValueForKey5' // should fail
})
```

The issue I am facing is it can take the value of any key instead of that particular key
So

```
myFunc({
    key: 'KEY1',
    value: 'ValueForKey2'
})
```

succeeds instead of failing.

How do I add the conditional restriction that only the corresponding key should succeed?

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQVsHIDSAogJoCMOAXFDgGoCGANgK4QBiA9gE54QhkDcWXISIAmClTpNWnbiDEDsVYQGZxNBs3ZceqgQF8Mh0JFggACrQ60AtokgAeeAD4oqTAEgA1j0reQbADMoeAF3ADcNCEp4AG0-QOCAXQw9AUMAxgA7AGNgAEs2TKhrEBYs7IAKCEzgDhBKOAsrWyR7ODsIJwBKdEMDDBKynIqPP0p8YjIAGgxwyPHJTRkeMhSuw0HykdmxpUmcGbmpBcitWQBWHDXDAdKt0Z890gPZiOOJU+W5K70uoA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your method as:

```
function myFunc<K extends keyof MyType, V extends MyType[K]>(
  entry: {key: K, value: V}) {
// function body
}
```

Where you define two generic types `K` and `V` where `V` extends `MyType[K]`, i.e. the value corresponds to the key.

See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=16&pc=1#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po+rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc+VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtajBVAtUAAWTwB1AAF5QABvRQlUAAcgA0gBRUIARk5+S5ADUGNB2JAAGLwMjcyB4IUAbnZJR5-IATMKxRKpbL5YrtaqORrQgBmHWc8WSmVyhV4S2qgC+wWSXFgqAo8C8iDw0o9AB5uRDVgoeMJ4oqSXSDvxRaHw9xhLGWgBtbkAXQAfAAKVGoMh4EUsqPF0Dc-g6PWQEWi50ASlZwVdij9AfMubZHNAZZFZqFvDVJWrtv7Nv19sVQsUjeC7Y9XeHvcV-b5gs5Q57o6l45rBodAFZOaAVPYONFcQwsbOG-P-Yvuxy+1z19qtxyd7XdbaD0bObexQ4A0HhkL6crOCC7A0N8bhmMw7AMMwkD8LA0DqIkDAgnoIheAARLyqwMIgNT6HhSQ4nh4AOKgnLCAAcpAEh4UEKgAPLfGQuyCChWiQMcqCOAorjSHgoBOIg8A6KMWD6CgCCIDCwhXLBEhypeoiGISixMKwHA8EEJRAA)

Answer (score 2):

Adding a second type argument - the key - will do what you want. Then you can use it instead of `T[keyof T]`:

```
type MyType = {
  'KEY1': 'ValueForKey1';
  'KEY2': 'ValueForKey2';
  'KEY3': 'ValueForKey3';
}
function myFunc<T extends Partial<MyType>, K extends keyof T>(entry: {
  key: K,
  value: T[K]
}) {

}

// Fails
myFunc({
  key: 'KEY1',
  value: 'ValueForKey2'
})

// Works
myFunc({
  key: 'KEY1',
  value: 'ValueForKey1'
})
```